# TypeError at /api/register/ 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-registration

I am trying to register users using django rest framework but this is the error i am getting, Please help Identify the issue

TypeError at /api/register/
'module' object is not callable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
'module' object is not callable
Exception Location: C:\Users\ben\PycharmProjects\buddyroo\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py, line 110, in get_serializer
Python Executable:  C:\Users\ben\PycharmProjects\buddyroo\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5

below is RegisterSerializer

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'first_name': {'required': True},
            'last_name': {'required': True}
        }

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

and RegisterView.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny  # <-- Here
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from api import UsersSerializer, RegisterSerializer


class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the name of the module (file) where RegisterSerializer is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the name of the module (file) where RegisterSerializer is defined is RegisterSerializer.py.

If this is the case, in the RegisterView.py you are importing the module RegisterSerializer and not the class.

So, it should be

```
from api.RegisterSerializer import RegisterSerializer
```

In Python it is common to have more than one class in one module, so I would advise you to rename your modules to serializers.py and views.py and put all your serializers and views there.

Of course, if they are many, you may split this and create serializers/views packages and put several serializers/views modules there: user_serializers.py, whaterver_serializers.py...